HTTP Authenticated Subject Alias Redirect
Given an HTTP REST service that manages identity data, for example, where a user resource is available at /Users/{id}, I would like to define a URI alias, /Me, that allows authenticated callers to access their own user information directly without needing to determine/utilize their unique resource identifier. The appropriate response and resulting resource representation would be based on the credentials provided in the Authorization header.
My question is regarding the appropriate HTTP status code to use if I want to redirect /Me callers to their corresponding user resource at /Users/{id}.

307 Temporary Redirect

The 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code indicates that the target resource resides temporarily under a different URI


308 Permanent Redirect

The 308 (Permanent Redirect) status code indicates that the target resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.


303 See Other

The 303 (See Other) status code indicates that the server is
redirecting the user agent to a different resource, as indicated by a
URI in the Location header field, which is intended to provide an
indirect response to the original request.



By description, neither seem to be a perfect fit:

My concern with 307 is that the target resource isn't really "temporarily" residing at a different URI.
My concern with 308 is that the target /Me resource itself does not consistently map to a single new permanent resource URI, but rather, the redirect Location for this resource varies depending on the underlying Authorization.
The 303 description seems more inline with the intent, but the use here seems like an unusual use case, given the following:

It is primarily used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent to a selected resource



Note: This question specifically relates to SCIM, but I'd like to discuss it more generally. The SCIM RFC suggests 308, but I'm trying to understand if this is an appropriate response given the aforementioned concerns. In lieu of a redirect, I may just return the user resource representation via 200 directly.

more info here: What's the difference between HTTP 301 and 308 status codes?  (Despite the title, there is also info on 307)

Thanks, @Luuk. That answer is informative, but doesn't quite clearly address the use case where the redirect is for an authenticated subject alias (i.e. a single resource, /Me, whose Location varies depending on the underlying Authorization).

Note: the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry lists the currently authoritative reference for each registered status code.  As of the time of this writing, the reference for 307 and 308 is RFC 9110.


My question is regarding the appropriate HTTP status code to use if I want to redirect /Me callers to their corresponding user resource at /Users/{id}.

Assuming that an HTTP redirect is the right sort of response, then the primary distinction between 307 and 308 is whether you want clients continuing to use /Me, or if you would prefer that in the future they use the redirect target.

The 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code indicates that the target resource resides temporarily under a different URI....  Since the redirection can change over time, the client ought to continue using the original target URI for future requests -- RFC 9110; 15.4.8


The 308 (Permanent Redirect) status code indicates that the target resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs. The server is suggesting that a user agent with link-editing capability can permanently replace references to the target URI with one of the new references sent by the server. -- RFC 9110; 15.4.9

When choosing an HTTP status code, the rationale is not nearly as important as the "what are you communicating to general purpose HTTP clients".
From your description, I'm guessing that you want clients to continue using the /Me resource identifier, so 307 would be most appropriate.
